# "No payment method" appears in checkout page for product with recurring profile

Tags: magento-1.9, recurring

I created a product with recurring profile in Magento ver. 1.9.3.1. However, I found that the checkout page shows "No Payment Methods" under the Payment Information section if the product in shopping cart had recurring profile, but all the payment methods were showing properly for the non-recurring product.

I have enabled the Braintree sandbox in the "Payment Methods" and the non-recurring products could checkout successfully with Braintree.

May I know if there is any config that I need to set in the Payment Method for the products with recurring profile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Magento supports recurring profiles only for `PayPal` payment system through the `Express Checkout method` only as default payment option that's why you are not able  to see `Braintree` payment method on checkout page.

You can see this statement on **[Magento user guide](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/archive/magento_community_edition_user_guide_v.1.8.pdf)** Page Number **290**

So I think you have to use `Paypal Express checkout` for `recurring profile` or any third party extensions.